# Aggregating and summarizing pandas data but slicing between non-continuous values in column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

All, I'm having trouble understanding how I could use groupby to solve this challenge, as most groupby examples I see obviously don't handle the distinction of non-continous values.

```
Timestamp 'Signal' 'Value
00:00:00     1        12
00:00:01     1        12.2
00:00:02     1        2.1
00:00:03     0        1.1
00:00:04     1        6.2
00:00:05     1        1.0
00:00:06     0        4.4
00:00:07     0        1.6
```

I'd like to take the last value and, in another case, the sum of the first 3 rows, because signal is 1. I'd then like to start over with a new sum/last for the last two rows, because signal is 1.

So something like this:

```
Timestamp Signal Value Sum Last
00:00:00     1   12    
00:00:01     1   12.2
00:00:02     1   2.1   26.3 2.1
00:00:03     0   1.1
00:00:04     1   6.2
00:00:05     1   1.0    7.2  1.0
00:00:06     0   4.4
00:00:07     0   1.6
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Series` which is create by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of shifted column `A` by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) first:

```
a = df['Signal'].ne(df['Signal'].shift()).cumsum()
print (a)
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    4
7    4
Name: Signal, dtype: int32
```

Then get mask for values by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) chained with column `Signal` which values are converted to from `0` to `False`s and from `1` to `True`s:

```
m = ~a.duplicated(keep='last') & df['Signal'] 
print (m)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
Name: Signal, dtype: bool
```

Last [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by Series and [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) `sum` and last add `NaN`s by [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df['Sum'] = df.groupby(a)['Value'].transform('sum')
df['Last'] = df['Value']
df[['Sum','Last']] = df[['Sum','Last']].where(m)
print (df)
  Timestamp  Signal  Value   Sum  Last
0  00:00:00       1   12.0   NaN   NaN
1  00:00:01       1   12.2   NaN   NaN
2  00:00:02       1    2.1  26.3   2.1
3  00:00:03       0    1.1   NaN   NaN
4  00:00:04       1    6.2   NaN   NaN
5  00:00:05       1    1.0   7.2   1.0
6  00:00:03       0    4.4   NaN   NaN
7  00:00:03       0    1.6   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Wow, amazingly fast. Thanks a lot!